# No comet option in -march option for gcc

Tags: gcc, compilation

I am trying to compile something, but when using `-march=comet` it doesnt work.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options

Here if you ctrl+f for "comet" you can see that there are no results.

Does this mean my cpu architecture is unsupported?

I have a 10400f

Comment: gcc 7 is way older than Comet Lake. Just use `-march=native`.

Comment: @PaulR alder lake and rocket lake are supported, and they are actually newer than comet lake

Comment: Kaby Lake, Amber Lake, Whiskey Lake, Coffee Lake, Comet Lake all use the Skylake microarchitecture, `-march=skylake` is a proper fit (if for some reason you need to avoid `-march=native`).